# Where does Google use C#

Tags: c#

Looking around **SO** user profiles and other sites, I have noticed that some high profile users who work for Google including [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) use C# as their main programming language. Or at least, it is with C# / .Net related topics that they are most active.
This has led me to conclude, or at least assume, that C# is widely used inside Google.

I was under the impression that Google uses C++, PHP, and some other secret G-Programming language only available to Google insiders.
All in all, I could not have imagined they use any Microsoft-related tools or technologies.

My question is: which Google products are made using C#?

Comment: As far as I know, Jon Skeet does Java development for google. C# is something _he_ does outside of his work.

Comment: I think that Jon uses Java at Google

Comment: As much as I respect the moderators' decision to close the question I do not agree with them about it being off-topic. What is the difference between this question and say, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754301

It DOES generally relate to programming and Software development. As a C# programmer, I like the fact that SO is written in C# and .Net. I have a handy example to refer someone to who would like to see what the technologies can do.

If there are any Google C# products, I would like to know about them, and so, I believe would other programmers.

Comment: Josto, that other question pre-dates programmers.stackexchange.com. And if not off-topic your question would still have been a duplicate of it.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I see what you mean.

Comment: I've been told by a friend working at Google that some teams at Android, Youtube, and some of their internal business engineering teams use C# at Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your assumption is incorrect.

C# is not widely used at Google. In fact, from what I've heard, there is actually very minimal use of C# in any official Google project.